# delete * all not allowed in sql?

Tags: sql

When we want to select all columns from a table we use

```
select * from <table_name>
```

then while delete we use

```
delete from <table_name>
```

why not

```
delete * from <table_name> is allowed here?
```

Comment: The `*` represents "all columns". Deleting does not care about columns, and it only cares about deleting the row. Therefore `*` is implied.

Comment: If you actually want to find the columns `values` which got deleted use `Output Clause` like `Delete from table Output Deleted.ColumnName`.`Select` statement is for `Projecting or choosing which columns to return ` where as Delete is used to delete rows not `Columns`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete is use when we want to delete a row, not a column

Answer (score 1):

Delete query deleted one row then using of * is not necessary.

In select you can select one or two columns or all of columns but in delete you can delete all column of row then * is not necessary because you can't delete one column

Comment: select query selected one row then using of * is not neccecary

Comment: in select you can select one or two culumn or all of columns but in delete you can delete all column then * is not neccecary

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` do not have any relation with column,rather it concerns with the rows of table..If you want to delete the certain column data, you have to go for `UPDATE` option.

```
UPDATE table_name SET <set value here> WHERE <condition>
```

As `DELETE` relates to rows, you can specify the rows need to be deleted by using `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE <condition>
```

If you have to delete all the rows, you can use [TRUNCATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188249%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option as it is considered as fast,efficient way of deleting all rows.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few ways of looking at it.

In relational algebraic terms, the SELECT statement is a combination of the select operation and the project operation. The select operation chooses a subset of the tuples of the relation and the project operation changes the structure of the tuples. Every relational algebra operation takes relations and produces relations. The select operation is really the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement; the project operation is the column list, the part between SELECT and FROM. Because the projection has to do with the structure of the resultant relation it just doesn't apply to deletion, which doesn't produce a result relation but instead destructively removes tuples from the relation. The structure of the tuples isn't relevant, only the criteria that choose them. So where SELECT maps onto two relational algebraic operations, DELETE only builds on one, so there's no syntactic support for the other even though it would be symmetrical.

You could come up with a way to make this syntax meaningful, but it would violate the DQL/DML/DDL distinction of SQL. Data query language only contains SELECT. DML contains INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, which change the tuples in a table, but not the structure of the table. DDL contains CREATE and ALTER statements and can change the structure of tables. I could see interpreting `DELETE * FROM table` as saying, clear out the values in the columns of these rows, but then how do we know if DELETE is deleting or updating? If we treat * as "actually delete these rows" and a column list as saying "don't delete the rows, but do NULL out these columns" then we're creating a shorthand for a situation that isn't likely to come, along with blurring the distinction between DELETE and UPDATE. Adding the context sensitivity is going to make things more complex in the long run. If we treat the column list as instead specifying columns to be removed, we're making a statement that can do DDL or DML depending on how it is used, and thus blurring the distinction from another direction. If you choose to mandate the * but not accept a column list, you're creating a false symmetry with SELECT and all the other queries that can involve an explicit column list.

So, this is just one of those things about SQL that you accept. It makes more sense as you get more proficient at SQL. For example, I suspect you think the * is fixed syntax in SELECT, but it actually isn't, it is shorthand for a column list.

Answer (score 0):

In context of select, for example "
**select * from [table]**" the character ***** represents all column. So if the table consist of X number of column, all of value in  X columns will be retrieved. The value will later being used by the application/displayed in SQL client.

In the context of delete, when we want to delete we do not need to get the information stored in the column, thus the * is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you want to delete rows. Use `truncate table <table_name>` instead of what you want to do in your question. That will delete all rows of that table